# How can I ensure that the hornet queues are there when my webapp starts in JBOSS 6.0?

Tags: spring, jboss, jndi, hornetq, jboss6.x

previous title was:

**How do I get a JNDI reference to a queue within JBOSS 6 using Spring?**

I configured a JMS queue like this, which is in a file mytopic-hornetq-jms.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration xmlns="urn:hornetq"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hornetq /schema/hornetq-jms.xsd">
    <topic name="mytopic">
        <entry name="mytopic"/>
    </topic>
</configuration>
```

My applicationContext.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="jmsConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/JmsXA" />
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="jmsDestination" jndi-name="mytopic" expected-type="javax.jms.Topic" />
</beans>
```

This is the output using the JMX Console org.jboss.naming.JNDIView:

```
  +- UserTransactionSessionFactory (proxy: $Proxy103 implements interface org.jboss.tm.usertx.interfaces.UserTransactionSessionFactory)
  +- UUIDKeyGeneratorFactory (class: org.jboss.ejb.plugins.keygenerator.uuid.UUIDKeyGeneratorFactory)
  +- HiLoKeyGeneratorFactory (class: org.jboss.ejb.plugins.keygenerator.hilo.HiLoKeyGeneratorFactory)
  +- SecureDeploymentManager (class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext)
  |   +- remote[link -> DeploymentManager] (class: javax.naming.LinkRef)
  +- SecureManagementView (class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext)
  |   +- remote[link -> ManagementView] (class: javax.naming.LinkRef)
  +- mytopic (class: org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQTopic)
  +- DeploymentManager (class: org.jboss.aop.generatedproxies.AOPProxy$4)
  +- XAConnectionFactory (class: org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory)
  +- ProfileService (class: org.jboss.aop.generatedproxies.AOPProxy$2)
  +- SecureProfileService (class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext)
  |   +- remote[link -> ProfileService] (class: javax.naming.LinkRef)
  +- queue (class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext)
  |   +- DLQ (class: org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQQueue)
  |   +- ExpiryQueue (class: org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQQueue)
  +- UserTransaction (class: org.jboss.tm.usertx.client.ClientUserTransaction)
  +- ConnectionFactory (class: org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory)
  +- jmx (class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext)
  |   +- invoker (class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext)
  |   |   +- RMIAdaptor (class: javax.management.MBeanServerConnection)
  |   +- rmi (class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext)
  |   |   +- RMIAdaptor (class: javax.management.MBeanServerConnection)
  +- BeanValidatorFactories (class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext)
  +- TomcatAuthenticators (class: java.util.Properties)
  +- XAThroughputConnectionFactory (class: org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory)
  +- ManagementView (class: org.jboss.aop.generatedproxies.AOPProxy$3)
  +- ThroughputConnectionFactory (class: org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory)
```

which in my book means, the topic is bound to the JNDI name "mytopic"

Nevertheless does Spring throw

```
18:45:29,636 ERROR [ContextLoader] Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsDestination': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: mytopic not bound
...
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: mytopic not bound
  at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:771) [:5.0.5.Final]
  at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:779) [:5.0.5.Final]
  at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:785) [:5.0.5.Final]
  at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:443) [:5.0.5.Final]
```

**UPDATE**

It seems, that it is not actually a problem looking up the JNDI reference, but actually that the hornet queues are not configured at the time when the application starts.

If I deploy the application some time later, it will run just fine, because at this time the hornet queues *are* configured.

Is there a way to specify that the application will not start untill the queues are, or is the a configuration option for the jboss to hold of deployment until the rest is started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have succesfully employed the "depends" mechanism in Jboss 4.2. With it you can specify that something depends on something else (either using xml descriptors or for ejb3 you can use annotations). Here is a link to get you [started](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/reference/build/reference/en/html/jboss_extensions.html)

Answer (score 0):

What if you added the `java:/` prefix (the same as you have for JmsXA)? i.e.

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="jmsDestination" jndi-name="java:/mytopic" expected-type="javax.jms.Topic" />
```

BTW, I don't see anything defined under `JmsXA` name in your JNDI dump. You might have a problem with that too.

Comment: I already tried different combinations. The JNDI dump is only the dump of the global namespace. The JmsXA is registered indeed under the java prefix, so it is not included in the global namespace, and that lookup work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used HornetQ, I've just for the sake of your question read the [tutorial on setting up Spring together with HornetQ](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/06/spring-3-hornetq-21-integration.html). There's a section there about setting up `jndi.properties`. This is probably to make sure HornetQ registers its stuff into JBoss JNDI context.

Are you sure you have a file like they suggest and it's placed correctly?