# How to ensure that HornetQ is deployed before any application in JBoss 6?

Tags: jms, java-ee-6, jboss6.x, hornetq

We have an issue, that if you start JBoss 6 with our Java EE 6 applications deployed, where one of them uses a JMS Queue, the related MDB won't consume any messages until you re-deploy the applications. The MDB is using a Singleton with a Startup annotation.

My research so far resulted in the assumption that this is caused by HornetQ being deployed after the application.
I also found some hints to get around this [here](http://community.jboss.org/message/561608) and [here](http://community.jboss.org/message/575346), but I neither was able (and by the way didn't like) to use JBoss specific annotation in my applications due to missing Maven dependency nor am I using any deployment descriptor file so far.

So my question is, how do I ensure, preferrably with standard Java EE annotations or HornetQ/JBossAS configuration file that the queues are deployed before my application gets deployed?

Comment: Same answer as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774292/annotate-statelessbean-with-depends-to-hornetq-jms-queue

Comment: @Clebert: Thanks for the hint, but my intention was to have in general the HornetQ system started before any MDB deployment without having to specify this dependency in each MDB - isn't this possible?

Comment: the latest version of the resource adapter is doing a retry until the destination is deployed. You would need the latest version though.